# Bluemix - Java Application - How to patch for Unlimited JCE Strength?

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-cloud, jce

My application is a pure Java package that integrates an embedded web container and it handles an Oauth 2.0 authentication flow.

Running a trace I've isolated an SSL issue by use of the JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.debug=ssl" configures in the environment variable and repeated the application "push" to activate the trace. It displays an issue regarding unrestricted JCE strength. See the messages:

```
Error log: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
Trace log: handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
```

This seems to be an incompatibility between the calling node (IdP) and the OpenJDK Java 8.

Is it possible to add a patch to the Java build-pack in order to activate the Unlimited JCE strength? Is this patch supported by a cf cli command layer, or Bluemix dashboard console setup, or does it require a packaged upload of an new image containing the updated Java security directories? What is the structure of the patch (for example by Maven package). This is my current push command:

```
cf push redoauth2 -p ./target/red-oauth-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -m 200M -t 180
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution by use of a differentiated Java build-pack which already contains a patch for the unlimited JCE settings. Here is the cf push command adding a -b argument, which fixed the situation.

```
cf push redoauth2 -p ./target/red-oauth-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -m 200M -t 180 -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix supports overlaying the JRE if you push the server directory.

Assuming you are pushing a directory called defaultServer, create the following directory:

```
defaultServer/resources/.java-overlay/.java/jre/lib/security
```

Download the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) unlimited strength policy JAR files from IBM and place them in the created overlay directory.

Push the directory using:

```
$ cf push <yourappname> -p defaultServer
```

These JAR files will overlay the default policy JARS in the Java runtime.

**UPDATE**

As of August 14, 2017, IBM Cloud (formerly BlueMix) Liberty buildpack now includes Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/updates.html#latest_updates

Comment: Bluemix Link is down.

Comment: Removed link but found out that BM is now including JCE files - see update